# Error after upgrading from Entity Framework 6.1.1 to 6.1.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are using Entity Framework 6 to operate our database. When we are using EF 6.1.1, it works properly and never encounters any error. Recently, we decide to upgrade our Entity Framework to latest version, 6.1.3. The upgrade is quite easy, but we encounter the following error after upgrading the reference to 6.1.3. Here is the callstack of the exception.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IvyBridge.Services.Core.Implements.AdminService' threw an exception. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an object named 'Accounts' in the database.
Result1 StackTrace: 
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
  at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
  at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
  at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
  at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
  at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
  at IvyBridge.Database.DatabaseContext..ctor() in d:\Project\TradingPlatform\Source\DataBase\MyDataBase\MyDataBase\DatabaseContext.cs:line 17
  at IvyBridge.Services.Core.Helpers.BrokerRuleCache.LoadBrokerRules() in d:\Project\TradingPlatform\Source\Services\IvyBridge.Services.Core\Helpers\BrokerRuleCache.cs:line 57
  at IvyBridge.Services.Core.Implements.AdminService..cctor() in d:\Project\TradingPlatform\Source\Services\IvyBridge.Services.Core\Implements\AdminService.cs:line 109
```

Our code is as following:

```
     public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
     {
         public DatabaseContext()
         {
             ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized +=
            (sender, e) => DateTimeKindAttribute.Apply(e.Entity);
         }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
        }
        ...
     }
```

How to use it:

```
    public static void LoadBrokerRules()
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var operation = new BrokerRuleOperation(context);
                var result = operation.GetAllRules();
                ...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.ErrorFormat("{0}\r\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

BrokerRuleOperation class:

```
    private DatabaseContext db;

    public BrokerRuleOperation(DatabaseContext db)
    {
        this.db = db ?? new DatabaseContext();
    }

    public ICollection<BrokerRule> GetAllRules()
    {
        return db.BrokerRules.ToList();
    }
```

What is the possible problem in our code?

Comment: SqlException: There is already an object named 'Accounts' in the database.. The error was very clear. Can you check any duplicate tables exists.

Comment: We are using the auto-migration to update our database. When we invoke the DBContext, it seems to try to re-create the database again.

Comment: If you run Add-Migration it will create differences. followed by Update-Database. If you changed only dll then you need not run these commands again.

Comment: We just updated the library, but did not run any PS script in the console. The problem still exists.

Comment: in Configuration  class, In seed method... find if any table data is exists then return. Ex: if (context.Employees.Any()) {return;}.